# how to check if one function from Predicate return true?

Tags: c#, boolean, predicate

I have a Predicate on c# (that include some functions).

i want to play the predicate but i want to know if 1 of the function(at least) return true.

for examples:

```
class Program
{
    public static bool fun1(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");

        return true;

    }
    public static bool fun2(int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        return false;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Predicate<int> pre=fun1;
        pre+=fun2;
        pre(2);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

i want to know if func1 ot func2 return true.

thanks!

Comment: Again what learned. I've never seen `+=` on a delegate before. Of course on event but not on delegate. I've to check what this does.

Comment: that for add function for the delegait conteinter

Comment: Yes that's clear but what does this mean with respect to the result value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
Predicate<int> pre = fun1;
pre += fun2;
bool result = pre.GetInvocationList().Cast<Predicate<int>>().Any(d => d(2));
```

Get all the available delegates. cast them back to `Predicate<int>` and then use `Any` to check if any of those returns true or not.

Note: if you dont do this the result would be equal to result of last delegate.

```
bool result = pre(2); // depends on last delegate.
```

Update:

`GetInvocationList` returns array of `Delegate` (not list). `Delegate` is base class of all delegates. btw you cant invoke them directly. there are two other ways to invoke delegates from base class. first is to use DynamicInvoke. it will return result as `object`, so you need to cast it back to `bool`.

```
bool result = pre.GetInvocationList().Any(d => (bool)d.DynamicInvoke(2));
```

Another way is to cast delegates inside Any.

```
bool result = pre.GetInvocationList().Any(d => ((Predicate<int>)d)(2));
```

Comment: In that case there is no advantage of using that instead of a `List<Predicate<int>>`. What does `pre()` return? Is that call valid for that delegate container?

Comment: the pre() will return the resualt from last functions that run

Comment: @Verarind see the update. i have tested it but i didnt see documentation yet.

Comment: Thx. In that case it's not worth to use it as a container. A `List<Predicate<int>>` will also work and usage is clear. But nice question and answer. Thank you.

Comment: "any" need to get IEnumerable + Func
the deleget is not IEnumerable?

why do you need convert it to list?

Comment: @DavidBachar i didnt convert it to list. `Cast<Predicate<int>>` will return `IEnumerable<Predicate<int>>`

Comment: friend thank for all
i not get you so well
GetInvocationList()

is back a list for you predicate
and when i use


        foreach (someDelegate d in my.GetInvocationList())
            Console.WriteLine(d.Method);


i can print all the name of the function on my predicate...
so i not get what you done

Comment: why it not work
            pre.GetInvocationList().Any(d => d(2));
it gave me error
'd' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method' 
why?
GetInvocationList return me list ,
list is IEnumerable
and any need to work on IEnumerable and get Func, why it not work?

Comment: @DavidBachar unfortunately there is no generic method for that. you should know that `Predicate<int>` is a delegate that inherits from the base class `Delegate`. the only method in .Net for this, is `GetInvocationList` that will give you array of Delegate (not list) and you need to cast items from `Delegate` back to `Predicate<int>`.

Comment: @DavidBachar it will give you the error because if you dont use `Cast` then all the items are from type of Base class named `Delegate`. you cant invoke them directly. first you need to cast them back to `Predicate<int>`.

Comment: OH. i get you
1) Predicate<int> inherits from Delegate(interface) & delegate or only from Delegate?


2)if  **bold**GetInvocationList()**bold** return me array of Delegate why i cant invoke them directly , so i need to cast them?

i know that Delegate is not Enumerable 
but when i done 
oreach (someDelegate d in my.GetInvocationList()) Console.WriteLine(d.Method);
that work . why?

thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96791/discussion-between-david-bachar-and-m-kazem-akhgary).